# My form instance is never valid

Tags: django, forms, view, instance

I'm making a social network in django and i've a trouble with the User Creation Form. 
Here's my code:

---

### views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST) #
        if form.is_valid():
            u = UserProfile.objects.create(first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'],...)
            u.set_password(u.password)
            u.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
        else:
            return Http404
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()

    return render_to_response(...,
                             {'form': form},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---

### forms.py

```
 class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):    
      first_name = forms.CharField(help_text="Por favor, introduzca su nombre",     required=True)
...

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['first_name',...]

def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

def validate_user(self):
    first_name_length = len(self.cleaned_data['first_name'])
    ...
    if not first_name_length > 0:
        raise ValidationError("Por favor, introduzca nombre valido")
    ...
```

---

### models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)...
```

and i'm using templates with form.as_p, but my form instance is never valid. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the signature of your form:

```
def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs)
```

and now look at how you instantiate it:

```
form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
```

So, you're passing `request.POST` as the *request* parameter.

You should really avoid changing the signature of a subclass like this. In particular in your case as you are not using or passing the request at all. If you do need to do this, you should do the same as with the `user` value which you get from `kwargs` (but again you're not using or passing that either, so I don't know why you're bothering to do it.)